# Is it possible to activate the mobile network manually?

Tags: android, networking, settings, wireless

I am developing a GPS application. I want to manually enable the equivalent of `settings location and security` -> `Use wireless network` I want to manually enable the option. Is that possible?

Comment: i want to activate mobile network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to activate wifi

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```